# How can I remove (uninstall) top (table of processes)

Tags: top

Is there a way to remove (uninstall) top (table of processes)?

Comment: What is your end goal? The `top` command is provided by the [procps](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/procps) package - I'm not sure it's possible to remove that without destroying your system. In any case, removing the `top` command itself doesn't prevent people from accessing the same information by other means (e.g. via the `/proc` filesystem directly).

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for that info.  I thought it was an app like other ones that I can just remove if I don't use/need it.

Comment: Why bother to uninstall this standard Unix/Linux utility? Simply don't use it. Is this an XY problem? What's behind your desire to remove `top`?

Answer (score 0):

Removing utilities that comes with a standard Linux installation might not be a worthwhile option.
It might even be a source of later functional problems within the OS; *e.g. attempting removal or update of python is a typical problem creator.*

If you have limited space on your system disk(s) then consider software you yourself have installed as options for removal.

`$ apt-mark showmanual | less`  will show you a list of software packages that has been marked as "manually installed" -
which happens if you have done `$ sudo apt install _package_name_` at some moment in time.

*Additionally; if there is more than one kernel version installed, those you're not using are often "free" to remove. `$ dpkg --list | grep -E '^ii.*linux-image'` will list them.*

`$ apt-mark --help` and `$ apt --help` will show more options.